# Permissions in iOS how to implement

Tags: iphone, permissions, ios4, wifi, ios-permissions

Is it possible to make permissions in iOS? I know in android that I can set permissions in my manifest that if you do not have WI-FI that my app will not run on your device. Is there something similar in iOS? Can anyone provide either code and tell me where to place or point me towards an API that can show me how to do that in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your application to be installed on devices that do not support wifi connection add array with `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key to your application property list and add `wifi` value in it (look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12) for more details)

Check also [UIRequiresPersistentWiFi](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12) property list key - may be it will also be useful for your purposes